# Theme switcher in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to save the user preferred theme (light/dark) in cookies. Can someone help me with it? I'm really bad at JS. I submit my current script.

**Stylesheets:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" id="pagestyle2" type="text/css" charset="utf-8"/>
<link href="file-upload.css" id="pagestyle4" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap.css" id="pagestyle3" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="hg.css" id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Switcher:**

```
<li class="nav-item" id="pagestylechoose">
    <a href="#" onclick="swapStyleSheet('dark.css');swapStyleSheet2('custom-dark.css');swapStyleSheet3('bootstrap-dark.css');swapStyleSheet4('file-upload-dark.css')"></a>
</li>
```

**Switcher JS:**

```
    function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
        document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
    }
    function swapStyleSheet2(sheet) {
        document.getElementById('pagestyle2').setAttribute('href', sheet);
    }
    function swapStyleSheet3(sheet) {
        document.getElementById('pagestyle3').setAttribute('href', sheet);
    }
    function swapStyleSheet4(sheet) {
        document.getElementById('pagestyle4').setAttribute('href', sheet);
    }
```

Comment: You can use this, if you don't mid of jQuery https://github.com/camsjams/jquery-style-switcher

Comment: I do mind Jquery answers when OP did not tag Jquery

Comment: This question does not show an attempt at storing the selected theme so it's hard to tell what you're having difficulty with. Note that a better way to switch themes is to use the [disabled property on link elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-disabled) and toggle it for the active theme. Here's a link to [an example implementation](https://guides.codechewing.com/js/disable-enable-stylesheet-javascript)

Comment: @SølveTornøe It's crazy that people are still using jQuery in 2020. See https://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you have a single function that get called when the button is clicked, specially that the stylesheet names are hard coded anyways

```
<li class="nav-item" id="pagestylechoose">
    <a href="#" onclick="changeStyleToDark()"></a>
</li>
```

..

```
function changeStyleToDark() {
  document.cookie += "style=dark";
  swapStyleSheet('dark.css');
  swapStyleSheet2('custom-dark.css');
  swapStyleSheet3('bootstrap-dark.css');
  swapStyleSheet4('file-upload-dark.css');
}

function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
function swapStyleSheet2(sheet) {
    document.getElementById('pagestyle2').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
function swapStyleSheet3(sheet) {
    document.getElementById('pagestyle3').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
function swapStyleSheet4(sheet) {
    document.getElementById('pagestyle4').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
```

Now to get the read the user style later you can use

```
function getUserStyle() {
  return getCookieByName("style");
}

function getCookieByName(cookieName) {
  var cookieString = RegExp(cookieName + "=[^;]+").exec(document.cookie);
  return decodeURIComponent(!!cookiestring ? cookiestring.toString().replace(/^[^=]+./,"") : "");
}
```

Now, on the beginning of the script, and whenever the page loads, check for the cookie and call `changeStyleToDark` if it's set to `dark`.

```
window.onload = (event) => {
  if (getUserStyle() === "dark") changeStyleToDark();
};
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply but when I refreshing my website it's still changing to the default theme.

Comment: The cookie saves in browser cache as style value: dark but after the refresh, I still have white layout.

Comment: @JohnCloud You just need to check `on load` if the cookie's value is `dark`, if so, change the theme. Check the added code.

Comment: I put everything according to your instructions (At least I think so) and still after refreshing the page I see a white layout even though cookie style=dark. Here is my javascript code. I put it in footer.php (maybe this is a problem). I also tried to put a fragment of the window.onload code in the header.php file in the <head> tag, but it didn't help. https://pastebin.com/8PV4rTyX

Answer (score 1):

Although it requires a little modification of your CSS, there is another solution instead of having to load different style sheets.

Load a default version, for this example, lets say its the light version. Then when the visitor wants the `dark` version, a class is added to the BODY called `dark`.

Then within your DARK version of the CSS, just add `body.dark` to the beginning of all CSS selectors.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lw7461ey/ (SO Snippets blocks localstorage so I used jsfiddle)

This way you can load all of the CSS files at once, you can even compress them if you wanted to.

```
var ChangeTheme = document.querySelector(".ChangeTheme");

if(localStorage.getItem("theme") === undefined){
   localStorage.setItem("theme","light");
}

function setTheme(){
   document.body.classList.remove("dark");
   document.body.classList.remove("light");
   document.body.classList.add(localStorage.getItem("theme"));
}

ChangeTheme.addEventListener("click",function(){
   localStorage.setItem("theme",(localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark") ? "light" : "dark");
   setTheme();
});

setTheme();
```

For your CSS for example

Lets say in light you have:

```
a{color:#000000;}
```

For dark, just change it to:

```
body.dark a{color:#ffffff;}
```